# Overwrite values from one table to another using

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable, overwrite

I have two tables, customer and newCustomer. For specific columns, I want to overwrite the column values of customer table with the newCustomer table. For example :

```
customer.firstname = newCustomer.firstname
customer.lastname = newCustomer.lastname
```

** I do have matching Ids for the two tables.

I can think of how to do this in terms of coding, but am having a hard time when thinking of doing this in SQL.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

Would appreciate any examples or hints.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have a table called Customer and newCustomer. So I want to make customer.firstname = newCustomer.lastname.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have some id that connects the two tables.  If so, just use `join` and `set`:

```
update c
    set firstname = nc.firstname,
        lastname = nc.lastname
    from customer c join
         newcustomer nc
         on c.customerid = nc.customerid;
```